# Can I add cookie with Spring SockJs websocket implementation

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

Can I add custom cookies over websocket in Spring SockJS implementation? The way we can add it with http request/ response?

Forget to mention that I see way to read cookie from headers :: HttpHeaders headers= session.getHandshakeHeaders(); -But I do not see a way to set headers. With headers I can read the cookies -but how to set it?

Answer (score 1):

This is all work-in-progress still, but at this time you can configure a HandshakeInterceptor on the DefaultSockJsService. That gives you access to the request and response before and after the handshake.

Comment: Discussed here https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/pull/29#issuecomment-2733120, for now have done without cookies